# why isn't gulp-filter filtering out less files in my bower packages

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less, bower, gulp

i'm trying to get all the files in my bower components using [main bower files](https://www.npmjs.org/package/main-bower-files) and filtering them according type using [gulp-filter](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter). it works fine when i filter out the js files like so:

```
gulp.task('bower_js', function() {
  var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js');
  gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {base: './bower_components'})
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_public/js'));
});
```

however running a similar task for less doesn't work (ie nothing goes through the filter):

```
gulp.task('bower_css', function() {
  var lessFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.less');
  gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {base: './bower_components'})    
    .pipe(lessFilter)
     // .pipe(less()) commented to narrow down the problem
    .pipe(concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_public/css'));
});
```

although if I run mainBowerFiles without *any* filter.. it dumps `.less` files content into my destination folder..

to give a specific example.. this is the relevant part of `bower.json` of one of my bower packages: bootstrap:

```
  "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
    "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"
  ],
```

`bootstrap.less` in turn imports other files:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";
..
```

and so on.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to get something similar to work for SASS with no luck. That is until I found that main-bower-files now has a [filter option](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files/commit/888ccbe01ea8efdcea05040a72e36756d1c6bb37) built in. It's a regular expression. Try something like this instead of using gulp-filter:

```js
gulp.task('bower_css', function() {
  var lessRegEx = (/.*\.less$/i);
  gulp.src(mainBowerFiles({filter: lessRegEx}), {base: './bower_components'})    
     // .pipe(less()) commented to narrow down the problem
    .pipe(concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_public/css'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing same issue with fonts folder, strange combo for main-bower-files (2.11.0) and gulp-filter (v3.0.1).
[Issue #53](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter/issues/53) in gulp-filter looks similar, the solution seams to be the basedir option.

main-bower-files + gulp-filter = not working

```
gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe(gulpFilter('**/fonts/*'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./demo/assets/fonts'));
```

main-bower-files + basedir + gulp-filter = working

```
gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {base: './'})
    .pipe(gulpFilter('**/fonts/*'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./demo/assets/fonts'));
```

main-bower-files with filter = working

```
gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/fonts/*'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./demo/assets/fonts'));
```

simple gulp.src + gulp-filter = working

```
gulp.src('bower_components/**')
    .pipe(gulpFilter('**/fonts/*'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./demo/assets/fonts'));
```